# how to hide my website header in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

how to hide my website header in android webview? I have tried javascript function in my mainactivity.java but not worked, Please hep, Thanks in advance!

This is Im tried

```
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {

            myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.get('header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                   "})()");
        }
```

Comment: `This is Im tried` and what is the result?

Comment: not working! please help

Comment: `not working!` any error messages in logcat? Maybe you are using wrong ID? You didn't show your HTML, so I can't help.

Comment: no error messages., How to find the correct ID for header?

Comment: `How to find the correct ID for header` - `You didn't show your HTML, so I can't help.`

Comment: you mean header.php file?

Comment: no, the HTML code of the page, where you are trying to hide the header.

Comment: Please edit the question, and add the HTML code which you are trying to hide header from. Not the web site url.

Answer (score 2):

hope you have added

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var header = document.getElementById(\"header\"); " +
                "header.parentNode.removeChild(header);" +
                "})()");
    }
```